# Jersey JSON to object conversion using MOXY not working

Tags: java, jersey, moxy

I am learning the jersey @POST REST call for a simple method which takes in json and returns a simple text. I am using MOXY with Jersey.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
      <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>
```

My method looks as follows:

```
    @Path("/travel")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String testServletPost(ThingsToSeeInParis thingsToSeeInParis)
    {
        if (thingsToSeeInParis != null){

            System.out.println("thingsToSeeInParis.isSeenEiffeltower() "+thingsToSeeInParis.isSeenEiffeltower());
            System.out.println("thingsToSeeInParis.isSeenLouvre() "+thingsToSeeInParis.isSeenLouvre());
            System.out.println("thingsToSeeInParis.isSeenMontMaetre() "+thingsToSeeInParis.isSeenMontMaetre());
            System.out.println("thingsToSeeInParis.id "+thingsToSeeInParis.getId());
        }

        if (thingsToSeeInParis.isSeenEiffeltower() && thingsToSeeInParis.isSeenLouvre()){
            System.out.println("Please shut up the lady behind me");
            return "OK";
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Its a lost case!");
            return "Not OK";
        }
    }
```

My `ThingsToSeeInParis` class is simple POJO class. Looks as follows:

```
public class ThingsToSeeInParis {

private boolean seenEiffeltower;
private boolean seenMontMaetre;
private boolean seenLouvre;
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean isSeenEiffeltower() {
        return seenEiffeltower;
}

public void setSeenEiffeltower(boolean seenEiffeltower) {
    this.seenEiffeltower = seenEiffeltower;
}

public boolean isSeenMontMaetre() {
    return seenMontMaetre;
}

public void setSeenMontMaetre(boolean seenMontMaetre) {
    this.seenMontMaetre = seenMontMaetre;
}

public boolean isSeenLouvre() {
    return seenLouvre;
}

public void setSeenLouvre(boolean seenLouvre) {
    this.seenLouvre = seenLouvre;
}
```

}

When I call this method from POSTMAN I get 200 response code but it always returns "Not OK". My postman calls are as follows:

[image]

No matter what or how many inputs I put I always get the same output. MOXY is just initializing all the values to default and that is why evaluation is not working. Can someone spot the issue in this code? Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Where's your POJO class?

Comment: Added in the main question sir :)

Comment: The class needs to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. Can you also confirm that the Content-Type header is set to application/json in the request?

Comment: the request is application/json indeed as you can see in the postman screenshot. About @XmlRootElement annotation, is it not needed for JAXB? Is it must if just using JSON and not XML? I will try it anyways.

Comment: MOXy is built on top of JAXB.